# Is it possible to run pytest totally silent?

Tags: python, pytest

I have simple test:

```
def test_noindex(data):
    assert 0
```

I need to handle this test by py.test, but totally silent (as i see py.test has exit code 1 for failed tests).

I tried:

```
py.test -s test.py
py.test -qq test.py
py.test --capture=no test.py
```

result is always the same: i see full report. What i am doing wrong?

P.S. Running on windows, executing pytest using `pytest.main([params])` in python code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@smassey's answer works in most cases, but since you execute pytest from Python itself, you need to approach things differently.

For example, have your python's `stdout` and `stderr` redirect to nothing while you run your tests. This can be accomplished with following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys

old_out = sys.stdout
old_err = sys.stderr
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, 'w')

print 'suppressed'

sys.stdout = old_out
sys.stderr = old_err

print 'restored'
```

`open(os.devnull)` opens your operating system's equivalent of `/dev/null` for writing. Having it redirect simply to `None` will not work, because `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` need to expose certain methods so that `print` won't throw exceptions.

There is also question: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Hm.. will try this.. thank you! I need to do it that way, because our QA asked me to make custom tests runner for them. I understand that rewriting tests runner for pytest is strange way to resolve problems, but they said that they know what they do. So... i just make custom tests runner.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply redirect all output, like so:

```
py.test test.py 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

This works for *any* output (stderr, stdout) of *any* cli app.

Comment: In fact, i am running on windows, and executing pytest from python code using pytest.main([cmd params]), so i suppose the only chance is to use built-in functionality :/

Comment: If you could run the entire thing in a .bat script, this could work on windows: `py.test test.py 2>&1 >NUL` (from what I read from here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true , never actually tried it out myself)